# Dynamic div style prevent BeatifulSoup to make code persistent

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I built this code to get a value from this site:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Brave Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
    }

url = "https://www.blockchaincenter.net/altcoin-season-index/#how30"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"style":"font-size:88px;  color:#345C99;position:relative;top:56px;left:calc(16% - 46px)"})
print(mydivs)

mydivstext = soup.find("div", {"style":"font-size:88px;  color:#345C99;position:relative;top:56px;left:calc(16% - 46px)"}).get_text()
print(mydivstext)

mydivsrough = soup.findAll("div", {"style":"font-size:88px;  color:#345C99;position:relative;top:56px;left:"})
print(mydivsrough)
```

The output is:

> [16]
>
> 16
>
> []

My current issue is that the value 16 is dynamic and will change the `div style` as well, is there a way to go one level up or to avoid the dynamic part of the div so I can safely implement this code?

Comment: How about a CSS-selector to select the three divs? `soup.select("div.bccblock div div")` This will return a list of all divs that are within a div within a div with a class `bccblock`, so you don't have to rely on the style of the divs themselves to find them.

Comment: @PaulM. , ok I did it but it's returning multiple div values, how to target specifically the one I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to extract the data you need. The data you need is present inside a `<div>` with class `bccblock`. But there are many `<div>` with that class.

I have identified that the data you need is present inside the first three `<div>`s. So I am selecting them and extracting the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Brave Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
    }

url = "https://www.blockchaincenter.net/altcoin-season-index/#how30"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

b = soup.findAll('div', class_='bccblock')[:3]
for i in b:
    print(list(i.stripped_strings))
```

```
['Altcoin Month Index', '49', 'Bitcoin Month', 'Altcoin Month']
['Altcoin Season Index', '12', 'Bitcoin Season', 'Altcoin Season', "It's Bitcoin Season!"]
['Altcoin Year Index', '57', 'Bitcoin Year', 'Altcoin Year']
```